Water coming out of exterior drain?
Please forgive me as I am not an expert. There is a drain pipe, as shown the photo that comes out in my mother's yard. From my understanding, I followed it and it collects water from the rain gutters and goes along the ground where it hits a few other gutter drains into a PVC pipe and then comes out of the side of the Hill. A few days ago, during the dead of Summer when it has been extremely hot and dry, I noticed there was water dripping out of it inconsistently, sometimes the flow would be more but then it would go to a drip and that went on for at least 6 hours but maybe longer. My mother is on that home almost 30 years and I have never seen water come out of it when it is not raining. The next morning the ground was still soaking wet underneath it but it was not dripping. I know there is no water going down those drains, so I'm wondering if it's possible that there could be water under the house and maybe going into a break in the pipe? Sorry if this question sounds stupid but I've been worried about water underneath the house lately...
Drain after stopped leaking

Is this a chance, or the first time you noticed it?  Normally pictures are attached to the question and not provided in external links.  Since it's an external link I'm not going to click on it, but first guess is that it's air conditioning condensate, especially if your mother's air conditioning has been running a lot recently.

inspect the perimeter around the home, any other wet spots
